# UWP Multiple MenuItem Views in NavigationView

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, navigationview, multiple-views

Is there a way in a `NavigationView` in UWP to have multiple "Views" for `NavigationViewMenuItems`?  The concept would be to have Categories or Folders as `MenuItems`, and when clicked or the `NavigationViewMenuItems` would slide out to the left and show the contents of the folder or category.  Then when navigating back out of the folder, the folder and categories list would slide in from the left again. I know I can change the `NavigationView.MenuItemsSource` in C#, but I'd like to instead have this done primarily in XAML.  I've tried numerous ways to do this, but can't seem to find a way that works.

I don't really have any code to demonstrate this, as this is a whole concept issue rather than a single bug that isn't working.  I have searched everywhere, and have found numerous articles/links about loading different views into `NavigationView.Content`, but nothing of changing the `MenuItems` portion.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this, or a link to a tutorial I could follow?  I can't imagine that this has never been done before, this seems like such a common-sense UI interface.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the default style for the NavigationView?

Comment: No, I wasn't even thinking along those lines....I know how to do a custom style, but how would that work in having multiple menu views?

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure this isn't a feature of NavigationView, I could be wrong. So what I would do is crack open the navigationview style, create my own style based on it and build in the features you want. I'd then opensource it and share it on twitter #UWP :-)

Comment: So essentially build a Templated Control that would work like this.  Yeah, I could do that... .  I'm truly surprised this isn't a built-in feature though, I have numerous Android apps that use this exact control.

Comment: Yeah, i have some examples of this in my UWP lib if you need help getting started https://github.com/DotNetRussell/UWPLibrary/tree/master/BasecodeLibrary/BasecodeLibrary

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

What you need actually is a Tree Navigator. The UWP has no such a built-in control for us. You could use the third-party control like [Syncfusion TreeNavigator](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sftreenavigator/getting-started).

See the code sample on GitHub: https://github.com/syncfusion/uwp-demos/tree/master/Navigation

Comment: I just installed it, and that is basically what I'm looking for, thank you!  Do you happen to know if it's still modifiable though, like could I still build a custom style or even Templated Control based off of it?  There are some things I'd prefer to change...

Comment: Check its document.

Comment: I was looking at it, but I've never used a commercial (non-free/open source) library, so I don't know how or if that would work.

Comment: I played around with this a little more, and it is possible to restyle the Tree Navigator, but I also discovered a negative to this control.  It can't be used within `NavigationView.MenuItems` without losing the functionality of being able to navigate to subfolders.  If I use just the TreeNavigator, then I lose the `NavigationView` features of having both a Pane and Frame layout. This basically puts me back at the initial issue.  So far I'm thinking the best approach is to follow the suggestion of @anthony-russell and Template the `NavigationView`.